# Ignoring .env files in my project with .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I'm doing a project in JavaScript (React / Node) and I want to ignore every .env files in it,

I don't only have one .env file at the root of the project, because I have a folder for the front-end and another for the back-end,

```
Root
  backend
    .env
  frontend
    .env
  .gitignore
```

And in the .gitignore file :

```
/node_modules
/backend/node_modules
/frontend/node_modules
/backend/.env
/frontend/.env
```

node_modules folders are ignored but not the env files,

The gitignore file is at the root, but should I have a gitignore file in every folder ?...

Comment: thank you, I had to do the git rm --cached <file> command

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solution:

```
**/.env
```

Explanation:

> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I just did it but I still can see the .env files in the folders, do I have to do sometihng else?

Comment: **/ *.env will work

Comment: it works now, I had to do what you said + git rm --cached <file>

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore by adding * before the file extension.
inside .gitignore add like 
**backend/*.env**
For more generic you can do like
**/*.env